# tridiagonal block matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let us consider a linear system of equations 
$$
Ax=b
$$ 
Where $A$ is a block tri-diagonal matrix, which is given by
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} & \dots & \dots \\
\dots & \ddots &\ddots & \ddots & \dots \\
\dots & \dots &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & A_{N,N-1} & A_{N,N}
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Where each nonzero element of $A$ is a tri-diagonal matrix. There are so many variations of Thomson algorithm for solving this system of equations. Now let us consider another linear system of equations
$$
Bx=b
$$
Where $B$ is given by
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
B_{11} & B_{12}\\
B_{21} & B_{22} 
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
$$ 
Where each element of $B$ is a tri-diagonal matrix. I have two questions.

- Is there any special name of $B$ like as $A$?
- Is there any direct method for solving linear system of equations $Bx=b$?

Answer (score 0):

I would call $B$ a 9-diagonal matrix.

A banded matrix solver could help - Look for "Matrix Computations" book by Golub.